# $project to contain the latest date from the group

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection that is filled with messages, and I want to get a group of how many messages there are per `room`.

- Gets messages within the last hour
- Where `gameId = 5550d868c5242fb3299a2604`
- Grouped by `$room`
- Sorted by `created`

When I add the projection, the `count` works, but `_id` becomes `null`, and `created` doesn't even return.

What I am looking for is `_id` to contain `$room`, `created` to contain the newest date, and `count` to be the count of items.

```
db.chatMessages.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            created: {
                $gte: new Date((new Date()) - (1000 * 60 * 60))
            },
            gameId: ObjectId("5550d868c5242fb3299a2604")
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {created: 1}
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$room",
            count: {$sum: 1}
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: {created: -1}
    }
])
```

Here is some example data:

```
{
    "gameId" : ObjectId("5550d868c5242fb3299a2604"),
    "message" : "For real?",
    "room" : "Main",
    "name" : "Hello",
    "created" : ISODate("2015-05-24T17:49:43.868Z"),
    "_id" : ObjectId("55620f376aa13616759f4f06")
}
{
    "gameId" : ObjectId("5550d868c5242fb3299a2604"),
    "message" : "Yeah for reals...",
    "room" : "Main",
    "name" : "Jim",
    "created" : ISODate("2015-05-24T17:49:59.135Z"),
    "_id" : ObjectId("55620f476aa13616759f4f07")
}
```

Here is the returned output:

```
{
    "result" : [ 
        { 
            "_id" : null, 
            "count" : 4 
        } 
    ], 
    "ok" : 1 
}
```

Here is what I am looking for:

```
{
    "result" : [ 
        { 
            "_id" : "Main", 
            "count" : 4,
            "created" : ISODate("2015-05-24T17:37:19.331Z")
        } 
    ], 
    "ok" : 1 
}
```

So what is causing this to break when I add the `$project`?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it by adding `created` to the group and doing `$max` on the column like this:

```
db.chatMessages.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {room: 1, created: 1}
    },
    {
        $match: {
            created: {
                $gte: new Date((new Date()) - (1000 * 60 * 60 * 20000))
            },
            gameId: ObjectId("5550d868c5242fb3299a2604")
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$room",
            count: {$sum: 1},
            created: {$max: "$created"}
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: {created: -1}
    }
])
```